# Why is this giving me an error?

Tags: javascript, variables, error-handling, variable-assignment

Why is this code giving me the following error message?

> TypeError: Object 97 has no method 'charCodeAt'

```
var str = "Caesar Cipher";
str = str.split("");
num = 2;
x = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    x = 0;
    while (x < num) {
        if (str[i].charCodeAt(0) <= 122 && str[i].charCodeAt(0) >= 97) {
        str[i] = str[i].charCodeAt()+x;
        }
        x++;
    }
}
console.log(str);
```

Incase anyone was interested in my final result: http://jsfiddle.net/zackarylundquist/8L9b5/

Comment: What are you trying to do here `str[i] = str[i].charCodeAt()+x;`?

Comment: charCodeAt(index) will get the ASCII code of the character at specified index on a string. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
str[i] = str[i].charCodeAt()+x;
```

Is converting the element in the array from a string to a number. A number doesn't have a `charCodeAt()` method, hence why you're getting the error. Use the following:

```
str[i] = str[i].charCodeAt()+x + "";
```

This will keep the element a string, and you will still be able to call the `charCodeAt()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't help it, I know it doesn't solve the op's problem exactly, but here's a nice caesar implementation (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z97HR/3/):

```
var str = ("CaesarCipher").toLowerCase(); // let's use only lowercase letters, no spaces
console.log(str);

var offset = 0;
var crypt = str.split("").map(function(letter){
    var offsetLetter = 97 + (letter.charCodeAt(0) + offset - 97) % 26;
    return String.fromCharCode(offsetLetter);
}).join("")

console.log(crypt);
```

Comment: Well a lowercase only cipher would not of cut it unfortunately but I did finish the code: http://jsfiddle.net/zackarylundquist/8L9b5/